# WCFTestClient exception on deployed service

Tags: wcf, wcftestclient

I use the WCFTestClient that is provided with visual studio to test my service. 
The thing is that the tool is working for the service that is deployed in wisual studio with my aplication. But if I try to connect to a deployed instance on another machine I get the following exception. Has anyone solved this issue?

The service uses `WindowsAutentication`.

```
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate oX0we6ADCgEBonQEcmBwBgkqhkiG9xIBAgIDAH5hMF+gAwIBBaEDAgEepBEYDzIwMTAxMDI3MDgzNTIxWqUFAgMCED6mAwIBKakLGwlCQVcuTE9DQUyqJzAloAMCAQOhHjAcGwRob3N0GxRsYmFpdGVzdDAxLmJhdy5sb2NhbA=='.

    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException, HttpChannelFactory factory)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at IBCMService.GetAllRegions()
       at BCMServiceClient.GetAllRegions()

    Inner Exception:
    The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)

    Inner Exception:
    The target principal name is incorrect
       at System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(Byte[] incomingBlob, Boolean throwOnError, SecurityStatus& statusCode)
       at System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(String incomingBlob)
       at System.Net.NegotiateClient.DoAuthenticate(String challenge, WebRequest webRequest, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate)
       at System.Net.NegotiateClient.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest webRequest, ICredentials credentials)
       at System.Net.AuthenticationManager.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest request, ICredentials credentials)
       at System.Net.AuthenticationState.AttemptAuthenticate(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest, ICredentials authInfo)
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmitForAuth()
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmit(Exception& e)
```

Comment: If your local machine is on `.net3.5` and the server you are trying to connect to `.NET3.5 SP1`, then you could check out this work around http://msmvps.com/blogs/alvin/archive/2008/11/14/net-3-5-sp1-breaking-change-to-wcf.aspx

Comment: Are machines in the same domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click on the config file in wcftestclient, click copy Full path, open the path it in an editor and check that the security settings match the deployed service configuration